# Transposition of state space form of a transfer function

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, control-systems, modeling

How can I transpose the output of state space model in *Mathematica*?
trying the [following code](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Transpose%40StateSpaceModel%40TransferFunctionModel[%7B%7Ba%5E2%2F%28s%5E2%2Bb+s+%2Bc%29%7D%7D%2C+s]) would transpose the top right symbol `s` instead of the matrices.

```
Transpose @ StateSpaceModel @ TransferFunctionModel[{{a^2/(s^2 + b s + c)}}, s]
```

[image]

Comment: `Normal` the model, operate on parts as desired, `StateSpaceModel` the result...

Comment: @ciao, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: You'll find all the details of those functions [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/)

Comment: @ciao, i uesd normal. It tries to give me [norm](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Normal[StateSpaceModel%40TransferFunctionModel[{{a^2%2F%28s^2%2Bb+s+%2Bc%29}}%2C+s]])!!

Comment: I'd venture you used `Norm`, instead of `Normal`?

Comment: @ciao Could you please talk technically clear about the correct command that I should enter?

Comment: I don't know how it could be any more clear. Take the state space model, apply `Normal` to it. Look at the result. Operate on that (or whatever piece(s) desired). Convert that back to a state space model with `StateSpaceModel`...

Comment: @ciao Could you please give me the link to what you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what a valid transpose of a `StateSpaceModel` is but here is an attempt:

```
ssm = StateSpaceModel @ TransferFunctionModel[{{a^2/(s^2 + b s + c)}}, s]
```

[image]

```
Transpose /@ #[[{1, 3, 2, 4}]] & /@ ssm
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like perhaps they snuck some changes in either structure or made transpose aware of structure in 10.x: Latter code blows up on 9.x (I used `StateSpaceModel@(Transpose /@ #[[{1, 3, 2, 4}]] &@(Normal@ssm))` for it to work). While that's a valid model, it's patently unclear what OP is after. Congratulations on 150, btw, and +1 here.

Answer (score 2):

To not be at the mercy of the internal representation of `StateSpaceModel` use `DualSystemsModel`.

```
ssm = StateSpaceModel @ TransferFunctionModel[{{a^2/(s^2 + b s + c)}}, s];
DualSystemsModel[ssm]
```

[image]

```
Simplify[%, Element[a, Reals] && Element[b, Reals] && Element[c, Reals]]
```

[image]

It will also work for descriptor systems.

```
ssm1 = StateSpaceModel@TransferFunctionModel[{{a^2 s^3/(s^2 + b s + c)}}, s];
DualSystemsModel[ssm1]
```

[image]